# Uniqueness of object_id in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is self generated object_id in mongo's collection unique across all the collections? Assuming my book_category collection, I have to put user_id to get all of the user's saved book category.

But how about update the data of book_category? should I put user_id inside my book category collection too?

```
module.exports.updateCategory = function(category_id,category,callback){
    var update = {
        name: category.category_name
    }

    Product_category.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":category_id},update,callback);
}
```

If the id is unquie accross the entire of my app then above code work fine. What will you do in my case?

Comment: @RobertMoskal can you give ur opinion on my case?

Comment: From the code you posted, I don't see where any cross collection issues come up. You select a document in a collection by it's id and update a field.

Comment: @RobertMoskal just imagine it's a library system, each user have books and book_category, will you store user_id within book_category? and when you want to update something, will you do double check? like check user_id and obj_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each **book** has an id and a user id, but the id is enough to uniquely identify the **book**. You have two common choices with **book category**:

It can be a collection that consists of a **book** id and a **category** id as well the id by which the book category is uniquely identified.  The **category** id points to some other collection of categories.  If you wanted all the categories for a book, you query by **book** id. If you want all the books for a category, you query by **category** id

Depending on your use cases, you could also simply hand an array of **category** ids from each book.

In neither case do I see any reason to involve the user id. Nor do I see any possibility of cross-collection id collision.